# Options for creating a Grafana API Token

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

My organization runs a grafana 7.0 instance that only allows SSO logins. I would like to create an API token for my user account but based on [these instruction](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/tutorials/api_org_token_howto/) it seems like doing so is not possible without supplying a password. Is this understanding accurate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Amal.Touzani mentioned, API key is created per organisation, not per user.

[Instruction](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/tutorials/api_org_token_howto/#how-to-create-a-new-organization-and-an-api-token), mentioned by you, needs admin password to authenticate the admin user during API token creation. Later on access level will be defined by role specified in request, in example it is `"role": "Admin"`. Role could be Viewer, Editor or Admin ([as mentioned here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/http_api/auth/#create-api-key))

Of course, all these steps could be done from Grafana Administration UI:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your user should have the permission to create API token but you don't supply the
password.
Based on the documentation , the Admin API needs (username , password ) to authenticate .
But API Tokens are currently only linked to an organization and an organization role , please see these links :

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/http_api/admin/

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/http_api/auth/

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/tutorials/api_org_token_howto/